# List of distinct dates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, date, datetime

I have the following code:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
//filling the list somehow
dates = dates.Distinct().ToList();
```

The code is basically working but I get the list of unique DateTime. And I want to get the list of unique dates since I don't need times at all here. Is there a nice solution?

My question differs from

[c# Linq select distinct date time days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875786/c-sharp-linq-select-distinct-date-time-days)

since I am not quering the database actually. I just want to filter the list.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx Overloads to the rescue

Comment: For what I can see the question is how to get the date without the time. then you could use a `.ToShortDateString();`

Comment: Or the `.Date` property to extract the date component only - as in the answer to the duplicate - and then distinct those.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about using a transform [SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx)?

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

Something like

```
dates = dates.Select(x => x.Date).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: The solution proposed is much better in my case then answers from the question you are considering to be duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that you can use construction like:

```htl
            List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
            //filling the list somehow
            List<DateTime> dates2 = new List<DateTime> ();
            foreach (var v in dates) {
                if (!dates2.Contains (v.Date)) {
                    dates2.Add (v.Date);
                }
            }
            dates = dates2;
```

but there can be better option for this.